# How to display non featured wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress

I have upload a plugin as 'featured posts' to add featured posts, also adding regular posts, both type of posts having default category(say, buy know). I want to display only regular posts(i.e non featured), but I unable to display only the regular posts, its displaying total posts(i.e regular plus featured). Please any one help me to display only the regular posts.
Thanks
Shama

Comment: You need to give us more information. What plugin do you use? Do you know how is it stored as featured: is it tag, post-type, category, custom meta field or something else?

Comment: Please clarify your question into 1. What end-result you are trying to achieve, 2. How you have tried to achieve it, and 3. What is the error or problem that is occurring.  Details about the plugins you're using, code you've changed (show original and changed code) should be included too.  Don't do this in comments, edit your question instead. PS white-space between your paragraphs is free ;-)

Comment: This may be better suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1):

```
$feature_ids=array();   

$query=query_posts('featured'=>'yes');

while(have_posts()):the_post();

$feature_ids[]=get_the_ID();

endwhile;wp_reset_query();


// now your feature posts id store in $feature_ids as array then
// in actual query

$query=new WP_Query('post__not_in'=>$feature_ids);

 // it will exclude the posts that are feature

if(have_posts()):while(have_posts()):the_post();
// yours data

endwhile;endif;wp_reset_query();
```